# Is there a crossed x nested hybrid for meta-analysis?

Tags: meta-analysis

My objective of a meta-analysis is to identify important predictors (~50 variables) on 1 response variable. I have a total of 550 observations from 7 projects. Before I can identify important predictors, I need to control for 3 categorical variables (project = 7 levels (p1,p2,p3,p4,p5,p6,p7) species = 3 levels (s1,s2,s3) and sex = 2 levels (m,f)). There are not observations in every combination, ruling out a crossed design (See image). There are no m observations (sex) for s2 (species 2). There are also no f observations (sex) for s3 (species 3). P1,2,3,4,6,7 (project) only use 1 species each and one sex. However, some species are *in* multiple projects, and one sex (m) is *in* multiple species and multiple projects - meaning the *nestedness* is not uniform throughout the study.

The only way I can think of explaining the experimental set-up is through stratifying. For example, for p1, p2, p3, p4, p6, and p7  species is nested within project - however this excludes rid of my sex factor (mf is only found in 1 project but 2 species). Are there any ways to simultaneoulsy nest and cross only certain factors?

[image: This is a layout of the categorical variables that need to be controlled]

Comment: You run the risk that whatever solution you find people will object that your comparisons of sex and species are based on different subsets of the dataset.

Comment: Are the 550 observations within the 7 projects independent? If not, you only have 7 degrees of freedom, not 550. Do you have access to the raw data such that you could combine into a mixed-effects analysis?

Comment: Hi @dbwilson - The projects are independent of each other, the observations within each project are not independent (ie same technician, time, etc.) Each project contributes differently to the 550 total observations. I do have the raw data - but am unclear on how to set up the mixed-effects model (I am assuming a mixed-effects model = mixed model) in that some variables are fixed - (i.e. species is fixed for p1,5,7 & separately p2,3,4,6 - and I am unsure how to include sex in this). Any help or points in a right direction is appreciated.

Comment: @mdewey Yes, that is one reason why I am trying to avoid stratification - do you think there are applicable methods to avoid stratification while being able to compare sex/species? Why or why not? Thanks